# What Is the "character" in string's definition?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

C11 defines a "string" as:

> A *string* is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and
>   including the first null character.   §7.1.1 1

It earlier defines a "character" as:

> 3.7  **character**
>   〈abstract〉 member of a set of elements used for the organization, control, or representation of data
>
> 3.7.1
>   **character**
>   single-byte character
>   〈C〉 bit representation that fits in a byte
>
> 3.7.2
>   **multibyte character**
>   sequence of one or more bytes representing a member of the extended character set ...
>
> 3.7.3
>   **wide character**
>   value representable by an object of type wchar_t, capable of representing any character
>   in the current locale

**Question**: What definition of "character" is being used in the definition of "string":
"character" in 3.7,
"character" in 3.7.1,
or something else?

Comment: All of the above.

Comment: Aside: Reading 3.7.3, a wide character string cannot use UTF-16.

Comment: Maybe helpful reading [Representation of Strings](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Representation-of-Strings.html)

Comment: @Deduplicator: Right.  16 bit `wchar_t` UCS-2 is a possibility, if the "current locale" includes only the BMP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A string is a contiguous sequence of data of type `char`.
The word "character" is used in two senses, abstract and practical.
From the abstract point of view, we first would have to define the concept "set of characters", in order to, later, go to 3.7 and say "a member of a set of elements for...".
This definition of "character" fits another standard: ISO/IEC 2382-1.

See [ISO/IEC 2382-1(character)](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso%3astd%3aiso-iec:2382%3a-1%3aed-3%3av1%3aen)

There, you can analyze a big list of terms related to "Information Representation".

**MY SHORT ANSWER:** "character" in the definition of "string" corresponds to c11.3.7.1.
The explanation is as follows:

**CHARACTER IN THE ABSTRACT**

A symbol is an intellectual convention of human beings.
So, the abstract symbol for "A" is a convention which we use to recognize different "graphs" like A, **A**, *A*, as being all "the same" thing (a piece of information, say).
The information is represented, then, by ordered and finite sequences of a set of (abstract) characters.
Next, you need to codify this abstract symbols to make possible their representation in information systems (computers).
This is done, in general, by defining a one-to-one correspondence between integer numbers (called **code-points**) and their correspondant characters in a given set.
An **encoding schema** is a way in that a set of characters is associated to certain numbers (code-points).
This encoding can change from one system to another ("A" has not the same encoding in EBCDIC as in ASCII).
Finally, we associate a "graph" to each character+code-point, that is, a written representation, which can be eventually printed or shown on screen.
The shape of the graph can change according to a font design, so it is not a good starting point to define the term "character".

**CHARACTER IN C**

In 3.7.1. it seems that C11 refers to another meaning of "character", intended to be a brief form to say "single-byte character". It is talking about code-points (that is, integer numbers associated to "abstract characters of a given set") that fit in exactly 1 byte.
In this case, we need the definition of **Byte**.
In C, a byte is an **information storage unit**, consisting of an ordered sequence of *n* bits, where *n* is an integer number greater than or equal to 8 (in general is 8, of course), whose value you can found by checking the constant `CHAR_BIT`, in `<limits.h>`.

There are data types whose size is exactly 1 byte: `char, unsigned char, signed char`.
The range of values of `unsigned char` is exactly *0...2^n - 1*, where *n* is `CHAR_BIT`.
The range of values of `char` coincides with `signed char` or `unsgined char`, but C11 doesn't say which of them corresponds to `char`.
Moreover, in any case, the type `char` must be considered different from `signed char` and `unsigned char`.

A string is, now, a sequence of objects of type `char`.

**WHY CHAR?**

The standard defines the representation of characters in terms of `char`:

**(6.2.5.3)**

> An object declared as type char is large enough to store any member of the basic
>   execution character set. If a member of the basic execution character set is stored in a
>   char object, its value is guaranteed to be nonnegative. If any other character is stored in
>   a char object, the resulting value is implementation-deﬁned but shall be within the range
>   of values that can be represented in that type.

**STRING**

Now, a string in C is a contiguous sequence of **(single-byte) characters** terminated by the null character, which in C is always 0.
This definition can be understood again in an abstract way, however in 7.1.1.1 the text talks about the **address** of the string, so it must be understood that a "string" is an object in memory.
A "string" object is, then, a contiguous sequence of "bytes", each one holding the code-point of a character.

This is derived from the fact that a "character" is intended to fit exactly in 1 byte.
It is represented in C by an array of type `char`, whose last element is 0.

**MULTIBYTE CHARACTER**

The definition of "multibyte" is complicated.
It is referred to some special encoding schemas that uses a variable number of bytes to represent an (abstract) character.
You need information about the execution character sets in order to properly handle multibyte character sets.
However, even if you have a multibyte character, it is still represented in memory as a sequence of bytes.

That means that you will represent a multibyte string again as an `array of char`.
The way in that the execution system interprets these bytes is a different issue.

**WIDE CHARACTER**

A wide character is an element of another set of (abstract) characters, different to those represented in the type `char`.
It is intended that the set of "wide characters" be larger than the set of "single-byte characters".
But this is not necessarily the case.

The relevant facts of the "wide characters" are the following:

- The set of "wide characters", whichever they are, can be represented by the range of values of the type `wchar_t`.
- These characters can be different from those represented in the type `char`.
- A "wide character" can use more than 1 byte storage.
- A "wide string" is a null-terminated contiguous sequence of "wide characters".

Thus, a "wide string" is a different object than a "string".

**CONCLUSION**

A string has nothing to do with "wide" characters, but only "single-byte characters".
A string is a null-terminated contiguous sequence of "bytes", which, in turn, means, objects of some the `char` types: `char, signed char, unsigned char`, corresponding to code-points of an abstract character set that fits in 1 byte.

Comment: I have a few problems with the precision of this phrase: "terminated by and including the first null character" So, concat functions drop characters? String length functions are off-by-one? String-end pointers are not one-beyond? The character set has to have a null character? What if it encodes its null character as something other than 0? What if it doesn't have any character encoded as 0? I think the terminator is not part of the string and not a _character in the character set;_ It is simply 0 and if the character set does have a character encoded as 0, it can't be represented in a string.

Comment: @TomBlodget Too many questions... I cannot properly answer all of them inside this comments.

Comment: @Tom Blodget I'll try one: "String length functions are off-by-one?".  The `strlen()` returns the number of characters that precede the `'\0'` - by definition.  So even with the definition of string including the `'\0'`, the definition of `strlen()` is, as you suggest "off by-one", in that it does not return the number of `char` in the string.  Instead `strlen()` is _defined_ to be affected by, but does not include, the `'\0'` in its return value.  `sizeof("1234")` does return 5.

Comment: My previous rhetorical questions were off-topic. The standard does require the execution character set to have a null character and to encode it as 0. So the terminator issue has no bearing on the question asked or @pablo1977's excellent answer.